# Angular 2 bump application version

Tags: angular, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a Angular 2 application as a sub module of a multi module maven project. I have configured this angular sub module in a way that I can build is with the main module and it'll archive the angular build directory. What I couldn't do for the moment is bump the version at package.json. Is there a way that I can programmatically do this ( Like in  **mvn version:se**t )